# Integrating the Steamworks API achievements into your game

Tags: c++, visual-studio, steam

I'm coding a game in Visual Studio 2015 and am wondering how to go about adding steam achievements to it using the Steamworks API, do I need to have my game on steam before hand or if not what's the process of adding achievements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the information you are asking for can be obtained at the [Steamworks website](https://partner.steamgames.com/).

But the quick answer to your questions (based on the Steamworks FAQ) is that while you can get access to it with a premium Steam account that has signed up for Steamworks, to actually use it with your own game requires a Steam Greenlight submission. This is because the API needs an "AppID" (of your game) to connect it to the Steamworks API.

Additionally, a quick look at the documentation shows that you can program it into your game once you have the API setup.

Hope this helped!